# Stack Exchange logo pixelated on modnewsletter subdomain

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com currently uses

[image: StackExchange (pixelated)]

instead of the beautiful svg used on other SE sites.

[image: Spritesheet]

Comment: It's no [tag:bug], it's a [tag:feature]!

Comment: I literally can't see a difference!

Comment: +1, very noticeable on high DPI screens, the PNG version looks blurry.

Comment: @Jan http://i.stack.imgur.com/GUdbq.png

Comment: time for a new monitor @JanDvorak or a pair of glasses...